# copying rows with a variable range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy rows from sheet 1 to sheet 2 using a variable 'r'. This variable is an output of another program. When I use the below code I get an error of 'Application defined' error. Can someone help me with this.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2)).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2)).Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2)).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 1, 2)).Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 2)).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 2, 2)).Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 2)).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 3, 2)).Value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You over-complicated it, just use:

```
  Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2).value
  Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 1, 2).value
  Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 2).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 2, 2).value
  Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 2).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 3, 2).value
```

The error was that you were using the `Range` method with only one cell as parameter, while it requires two cells and returns the range that joins them. You could use it to further simplify your code into one statement:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 2)).value = _
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 3, 2)).value
```

And further:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B4").value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & r).Resize(4).value
```

Comment: Got it ! thanks for such a quick response! Also, I am new to VBA, would you mind suggesting a book that would help me cover basic topics.

Comment: @Muni0408 I dont have a specific recommended book, but there are plenty out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also copy multiple values at once to multiple areas:

```
[Sheet1!C1:C4,Sheet1!C6:C9] = [Sheet2!B2:B5].Value
```